# How to recreate a GET request from an HTML form with a different trigger

Tags: javascript, html, http, get

I have an HTML form:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="seq" placeholder="Search by ID">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

when submitting the string `000` for example, this sends the `GET` request:

```
myurl/?seq=000
```

and the page reloads with the extra information. so far so good.

How can I recreate this exact behaviour but with a different trigger instead of the submit button for sending the `GET` request? for example, I attempted to use an `onkeyup` to link to a javascript function but I cannot find a way of making a simple javascript GET request that actually loads a page.

Comment: Share what you tried

Comment: like <input type="text" name="seq" placeholder="Search by ID" onkeyup="this.parentNode.submit()"> ?